# Centre elements of nested DIVs based its parent DIV in a fluid environment

Tags: jquery, html, css

My requirement:
How can I set all nested DIVs to match its parent size. Then centre all nested DIVs based on the sale and position of its parent DIV in a fluid environment?

```
<style type="text/css">
    #mainContainer {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    height: 400px;margin: auto;

}
.cont1{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    margin: auto;
}
.cont1inner{
    height: 100%;
}
.cont2 {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    margin: auto;
}
.cont3{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    margin: auto;
}
</style>

  <body>
  <div id="wCont">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="mainContainer">
          <div class="cont1">
            <img class="cont1inner" src="http://img42.com/PWehV+">
          </div>
          <div class="cont2">
            <img id="somethingA" src="http://img42.com/PWehV+">
          </div>
          <div class="cont3">
            <img id="somethingB" src="http://img42.com/PWehV+">
          </div>
      </div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Example: `mainContainer` is set to height:75%; and it has 3 DIVs inside it. When the window is resized `mainContainer` should maintain height: 75% and 3 DIVs inside it should also maintain its proportions accordingly.

Comment: I think a http://jsfiddle.net would help us out here, if it's possible

Comment: Do 3 inner div have the same width (1/3 of parent div)?

Comment: @Giorgio: no. They are different sizes.

Comment: So, if I get your idea, you would like to create 3 overlapping images with different sizes. When you resize container, all images must resize keeping their proportions, right?

Comment: @Niklas: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ys3mhz8/

Comment: @Giorgio: Correct. Here is an JSFiddle. This should give you a better idea. http://jsfiddle.net/2ys3mhz8/ (the 3 images should be aligned to the centre and when the browser widow is resized the 3 images also should resize proportionately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Images are centered both vertically and horizontally

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="content" id="one" src="http://img42.com/PWehV+" />
    <img class="content" id="two" src="http://img42.com/PWehV+" />
    <img class="content" id="three" src="http://img42.com/PWehV+" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html {
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    height:75%;
    border:1px solid green;
    position:relative;
}

.content {
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
}

#one {
    z-index:1;
    height:80%;
    top:10%;
}

#two {
    z-index:2;
    height:50%;
    top:25%;
}

#three {
    z-index:3;
    height:20%;
    top:40%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/php8hy5h/)**

You must execute jquery code on window load to allow images to be fully loaded (otherwise image width is 0px and centering function doesn't work). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a percentage in CSS requires that the parent div have a specified size, either by px or percentage itself. You could try to assign heights and widths of all divs leading up the chain but that might get messy.

What I'd propose is letting the inner divs inherit their size from the mainContainer, which gets it's size based on window size using Javascript. I've made a basic [JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/np2bxeye/)  similar to your example with the code a little tidied up.

In that fiddle, the height and width of the contentWrapper (mainContainer) is set to the window height and width, but you could easily change that with a bit of math or modified JS.

HTML:

```
<div id='contentWrapper' class="container">
    <div class='contentContainer'>
        <img id="contImg1" class="contentimage" src="http://img42.com/PWehV+"/> 
    </div>
    <div class='contentContainer'>
        <img id="contImg2" class="contentimage" src="http://img42.com/PWehV+"/> 
    </div>
    <div class='contentContainer'>
        <img id="contImg3" class="contentimage" src="http://img42.com/PWehV+"/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.contentContainer{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 33%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#contentWrapper').height($(window).height());
    $('#contentWrapper').width($(window).width());
});
```

I also put some border colours on there so you could see what's going on. Does that help?

**EDIT:**

New JSFiddle with different images where their size scales with the size of their container. At this stage, the container resizes with window size, but that's easily changed. http://jsfiddle.net/np2bxeye/3/

Comment: Thanks. My requirement is to overlap the images one over the other with a 100% scale.

Comment: A scale dependent on the image size or the size of other elements?

Comment: Height of the images depends on the window height while maintaining its aspect-ratio.

Comment: Okay I've got that sorted. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/np2bxeye/1/
I'll work on your overlapping thing now

Comment: Thanks Sean :). I was looking for something like Giorgio's answer.